# Trigger reindentation after snippet has expanded to word in 'indentkeys'

Tags: indentation, filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

The ftplugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) provides the file [`indent/tex.vim`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/indent/tex.vim) with following line

```
setlocal indentkeys+=[,(,{,),},],\&,=item,=else,=fi
```

> **`'indentkeys'` `'indk'`**  string  (default `"0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e"`)
>      *local to buffer*
>       A list of keys that, when typed in Insert mode, cause reindenting of
>       the current line.  Only happens if `'indentexpr'` isn't empty.
>       The format is identical to `'cinkeys'`, see [|indentkeys-format|](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#indentkeys-format).

Consider this list environment:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item <CURSOR> 
\end{itemize}
```

When you enter a newline and then a second `\item`,
at first the cursor will be indented to the second level (`sw=2`)

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
    <CURSOR>
\end{itemize}
```

then when you enter manually `\item`, the line will be reindented and you get the desired indentation

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
  \item <CURSOR>
\end{itemize}
```

However, if you do the same by using the UltiSnips snippet `it` (from [honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/tex.snippets))

```
snippet it "Individual item" b
\item $0
endsnippet
```

you end up with an unintended second level indentation of the second `\item`:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item 
    \item <CURSOR>
\end{itemize}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

This has already been raised on the [issue tracker of UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/913), but I hope to find here a wider audience for this issue. BTW https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template claims to support reindentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually fix the indent by typing `CTRL-F` (this is documented at `:help indentkeys-format`).  Thus, an autonomous solution would be to issue this key-press after snippet expansion.

```
global !p
def fix_indent(snip):
    vim.eval('feedkeys("\<c-f>")')
endglobal

post_expand "fix_indent(snip)"
snippet it "Individual item" b
\item $0
endsnippet
```

Comment: Thanks for that ! Though, we need to add this `post_expand "fix_indent(snip)"` to every snippet we want to fix the indent. Wouldn't it be nice to fix indent for *every* snippet when `autoindent` is on ? UltiSnips doesn't seems to be able to do that.